# Will rooting or flashing relock my unlocked Android device?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing

I bought an Haier w718 online from China. It is unlocked but they didn't put Google Play on it. If I root it or flash it will that relock the phone?

Answer (score 4):

No, since it is factory unlocked, nothing will ever relock your phone.

Comment: Technically, it seems to be possible an update really does re-lock the boot loader, as it currently seems to [happen to Galaxy S4 users on AT&T, Sprint, and Verizon](http://www.techshout.com/software/2013/10/samsung-galaxy-s4-receives-software-upgrade-on-att-sprint-verizon/). But it's unlikely to happen with custom ROMs.

Comment: Yes, but the Galaxy S4 is not sold unlocked. Here it is a smartphone that comes pre-unlocked (like many chinese devices)

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days of the ZTE Blade there was a ROM that [sim] unlocked the handset, flashing another rom would remove that unlock, but like @Shywim says if it is factory unlocked it is unlikely that flashing another ROM will lock it and like @Izzy says it is also unlikely to happen in a custom rom